# How to not push ImageView off of screen with Long TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my imageview to stay directly to the right of my textview.  I can accomplish this by setting **toLeftOf** in the attributes for TextView.  But for really long text strings, I have ellipses set, and after it reaches the width of the layout, it'll push the ImageView off as well.

I can have the **ImageView** displayed by setting gravity to 1 for TextView, but then the ImageView is anchored to the right.  What should I do?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="MY TEXT TO THE LEFT"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_button"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/some_img"        
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So w/ setting the weight=1, that hugs the image to the far right,  i need it to be dynamic and be to the right of the textview at all times and then when the width of the textview becomes longer than the parent, for the image to not get pushed off screen.

Comment: Can you add your XML layout file to give a better idea of what you're facing with your layout? Also, please include the screenshots of what you want and what you have got. This will help others in better answering your question.

Comment: I have added some of the xml @MDNaseemAshraf

Comment: Or even better, can i just add my image to the top right of the textview?  Have it overlayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set **paddingRight** to the size of the image button, inside the textview and I used **alignRight** on my image button.
And changed the container to **RelativeLayout.**  It works as intended!!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingRight="22dp"
        android:text="MY TEXT TO THE LEFT"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_button"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title_view"
        android:background="@drawable/some_img"        
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and set your textView width to `0dp` (also called `match constraint`).

The result will cause your textView to drop a line if the is a lot of text.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="something"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="this is really long text and it wont push the green image because of   android:layout_width attribute"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And it will look like this :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use `LinearLayout` with the `orientation="horizontal"` attribute . Than set the `weight_sum = 100` for the  LinearLayout , and than for your TextView and ImageView , just place the weight attribute according to what you want . Hope it helps .

Comment: It still pushes the ImageView off.

Comment: set weight to both imageview and textview